# Logical AND operator in mySql REGEXP?

Tags: mysql, regex

I use MySql REGEXP:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE title REGEXP "dog|cat|mouse";
```

The dataset is small, so I am not concerned about performance.  And I prefer this over LIKE notation, because I do not have to concatenate a bunch of "LIKE" statements.

However, the above notation uses a logical OR operator.  Is there a logical AND operator, so that only rows containing all of the keywords are matched?

(I am using InnoDB so fulltext search not an option)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's really no nice solution except concatenating ANDs:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE title REGEXP "dog"
AND title REGEXP "cat"
AND title REGEXP "mouse"
```

The regular expression would otherwise look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE title REGEXP "(dog.*cat.*mouse)|(dog.*mouse.*cat)|(mouse.*dog.*cat)|(mouse.*cat.*dog)|(cat.*dog.*mouse)|(cat.*mouse.*dog)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add several conditions with `AND` between them:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE title REGEXP "dog" AND title REGEXP "cat" AND title REGEXP "mouse";
```

Maybe REGEXP is not necessary here and you may use [INSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) instead (regular expressions are usually slower):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE INSTR(title, "dog") AND INSTR(title, "cat") AND INSTR(title, "mouse");
```

Answer (score 0):

`AND` operation may be only accessible by the mysql-AND:

```
WHERE title REGEXP 'dog' AND title REGEXP 'cat' AND title REGEXP 'mouse'
```

this will only show those entries where all the keywords are in the title field. like

```
title = "this is about mouse, cat and dog"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use full text search in boolean mode:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(colmun_name) AGAINST('+dogs +cat' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

You must index your table first:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT(column_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your title contains all the search terms, for example:

`Anything mouse anything cat anything dog anything`

Then you will have all the search terms in a three times repeated title in any order (for example dog, cat and mouse).

`Anything mouse anything cat anything DOG anything`

`Anything mouse anything CAT anything dog anything`

`Anything MOUSE anything cat anything dog anything`

So you can do this without concatenating ANDs with:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE REPEAT(title,3) RLIKE '.*dog.*cat.*mouse.*';`