# How to manipulate text in PHP to have single quote and coma

Tags: php, join, explode, implode, text-manipulation

My question must be simple but I can't figure how to do that:

```
$input = "Hello, Beautiful, World";
```

and

```
$expected_output = "'Hello','Beautiful','World'";
```

I know I can split text by `explode(" ", $input);`

but how to join with ', ?

Why I need it?
I need to have it to prepare MySQL query like

```
SELECT value FROM tab_settings WHERE name IN ('Hello', 'Beautiful', 'World')
```

from $input

Comment: Take a hint from your own comment *I need to have it to prepare MySQL query like* and look at how to do this with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below snippet for the same

```
echo "'".implode("','",explode(", ", $input))."'";
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/T3jcF)

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP

```
SELECT * FROM author WHERE aut_name REGEXP 'hello|benny|meny';
```

Read here [Logical AND operator in mySql REGEXP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687136/logical-and-operator-in-mysql-regexp)

Answer (score 0):

This probably answers your specific question:

```
<?php
$subject = "Hello, Beautiful, World";

preg_match_all('/(\w+)/', $subject, $words);
$words = $words[1];

$tokens = [];
array_walk($words, function($word) use (&$tokens) {
    $tokens[] = "'" . $word . "'";
});
$tokens = implode(',', $tokens);

var_dump($tokens);
```

The output obviously is:

> string(27) "'Hello','Beautiful','World'"

---

But please allow us to offer a hint here:

The strategy you follow to construct sql queries in such a string based manner is ultimately a very bad idea, since it makes your code vulnerable to what is usually referred to as "sql injection attacks". You want to prevent that.

Please start reading about the advantages of using the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" to prevent such vulnerabilities.